# How to create task using schtasks.exe with multiple days of month

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I try to create this scheduled task using the command line:

[image]

[image]

I tried:

> schtasks.exe /Create /tn test1 /tr notepad.exe /sc montly /m jan,feb /d 12,27

but it seems that /d can get only one parameter, for example: /d 12

How can I create the same task as in the wizard? I want to create a task that runs every 12 and 27 of january and febuary.

Thanks,
Inbal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do it, is by using xml and pass it as a parameter to the /create command.